# How to replace one word with another in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, replace

In each of my posts, there is a string: "Posted on 22 October by admin".
I want to replace it with the same statement but in another language.

I have installed the following plugins: Word Replacer, Text Replace, Word Filter Plus and none of them does that.

Comment: And all the other strings should remain? I mean, change the blog language is not a solution?

Comment: I want the strings in all post to be "Posted on ....." but in another language. Not only in one post.

Comment: I see, but what I've asked is, that all other string should remain, like `comment`, `Next entry`, etc... ?

Comment: No ,there is no need to remain. I have tried to change the language of the blog but it is on the language I want the change. i.e. that's not the problem

Comment: so, check your `wp-config.php`. At the end of that, there will be a line like `define('WPLANG', 'en_EN');` You can change the language of your blog with change that constant. If you tell me the desired language, then I can help you, should you replace the `en_EN`.

Comment: There is no such file wp-config.php. I press Appereance -> Editor and I can't see such file among the other pages .

Comment: This file is where the document root is. Do you have an FTP access to your website?

Comment: I don't know ,how can I check that?

Comment: If you don't know, then probably you have not. If you can not access your PHP files, we can't help you.

Comment: I can access my php files and change them but the one you said me is not among them.

Comment: No, you can access *some* of your php files through the WordPress admin. Most of the time, you can't see all of your files through this interface. You need access to the *actual* files on the server. This can be done by getting FTP access to your server, and is not something we can help you achieve through the WordPress dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

This will be done on the actual theme files.

Find these two files:

```
post.php
page.php
```

and any other which start with post or page (`post-template.php`) and look for a line similar to this:

```
<p>Posted on <?php the_date();?> by <?php the_author(); ?></p>
```

Then just amend the text to what you want.

To change date to the correct language, you will need to get a translation file installed.

Read more about that here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Date_and_Time_Locale_Settings

Comment: This won't translate the Month name...The OP will need a localized date format for that.

Comment: Added amendment for translations for yah

Comment: The date is in tha language I want . Posted on ... by is in english only.

Comment: Then do what my answer says and find those files in the theme folder and amend them to what you want :)

Comment: there in no such files.

Comment: Then do a theme-wide search. It's definitely in your theme template files...somewhere.

Comment: There must be, otherwise your theme wouldnt work. look in wp-content/themes/THEME-NAME/

Comment: I haven't installed WordPress so I don't have directories like that. I change the site with the bottons of the dashboard.

Comment: Right, try going to themes -> editor and finding the files. If you dont have access to this then you will need to gain FTP access to the server or have someone who does have access change the files.

Comment: I did that but I can't see post.php and page.php among my other files composing my web site.

Comment: You need to get proper FTP access to your theme files.